# Is that possible to clean a contour plot in skimage?

Tags: scikit-image

I have this thought this morning and I found `scikit-image` probably can solve the problem. Simply speaking I want to remove the level labels and other unnecessary features in a contour raster image and get the locations of the contour lines.

Like this image:
[contour image with features to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfNC0.png).

But after reading a while I became unsure if it could be done. My consideration is the following:

1) `find_contours` may find the contour lines, but I think all other features (arrows and lables) will also included.

2) closing may remove the labels, but I found contour lines are also removed, I think it is because they are just thin lines and the bright regions will be connected if using closing function.

3) the arrows are mostly connected with the contour lines, so these features cannot be considered as individual objects. They may be the most difficult part to be removed.

What I want to get help at is to know if it is possible to remove the labels and arrows to get contour lines in `skimage`. If so, I will continue to learn the package.

Comment: I have edited your question, please have a look to see if it is ok.

Comment: Yes, it is OK. I am sorry for the really bad formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial solution to your problem. The basic idea is to consider the network of interconnected lines as a graph, and to remove the small edges of this graph because they correspond (mostly) to arrows and to labels. A first step is to compute the skeleton of the binarized phase.

[image: Detected contours]

Of course the result is not perfect, you can adapt the different parameters of the script below to find the solution that you consider best. If you need to repeat this segmentation on a large number of images, you can also try to select manually the edges of the graph that you want to keep, as a training set, and to use a machine learning algorithm to classify which edges to keep (using features of the edges such as length, number of other connected edges, direction, straightness, ...).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io, morphology
from scipy import ndimage

def skel_to_graph(skel):
    """
    Transform skeleton into its branches and nodes, by counting the number
    of neighbors of each pixel in the skeleton
    """
    convolve_skel = 3**skel.ndim * ndimage.uniform_filter(skel.astype(np.float))
    neighbors = np.copy(skel.astype(np.uint8))
    skel = skel.astype(np.bool)
    neighbors[skel] = convolve_skel[skel] - 1
    edges = morphology.label(np.logical_or(neighbors == 2, neighbors ==1),
                            background=0)
    nodes = morphology.label(np.logical_and(np.not_equal(neighbors, 2),
                                            neighbors > 0), background=0)
    length_edges = np.bincount(edges.ravel())
    return nodes, edges, length_edges

# Open image and threshold
image = io.imread('contours.png')
im = image < 200
im = morphology.binary_closing(im, np.ones((5, 5)))

# Remove small connected components (small arrows)
only_big = morphology.remove_small_objects(im, 400)

# Skeletonize to get 1-pixel-thick lines
skel = morphology.skeletonize(only_big)
skel_big = morphology.remove_small_objects(skel, 30, connectivity=2)
nodes, edges, length_edges = skel_to_graph(skel_big)

# Keep only long branches of the skeleton
# The threshold can be adjusted
threshold = 35
long_edges = (length_edges < threshold)[edges]
edges[long_edges] = 0

# Visualize results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.contour(edges > 0, [0.5], colors='red', linewidths=[2])
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```